# redirect an exact match url to another url .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect an exact match url to another url. Site is installed in a subdomain. But when i use `^` and `$` my redirect does not work.

`Redirect 301 ^/p/tv-video/?$ https://sitename.com/p/tv/`

but

`Redirect 301 /p/tv-video https://sitename.com/p/tv/` does work

Wondering what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Remove ^ from start and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It' because `Redirect` does not work with regular expression. For that use `RedirectMatch` directive.

**Redirect** Directive
Description:    Sends an external redirect asking the client to fetch a different URL
Syntax: Redirect [status] [URL-path] URL

**RedirectMatch** Directive
Description:    Sends an external redirect based on a regular expression match of the current URL
Syntax: RedirectMatch [status] regex URL

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_alias.html